# converting multiple comma separated columns into rows

Tags: oracle

I have an Oracle table which holds comma separated values in many columns. For example :

```
Id  Column1 Column2
1   A,B,C   H
2   D,E     J,K
3   F       L,M,N
```

I want to split all the columns into rows and the output should be this :

```
ID  Column1 Column2
1      A       H
1      B       H
1      C       H
2      D       J
2      D       K
2      E       J
2      E       K
3      F       L
3      F       M
3      F       N
```

I found some suggestions which uses regexp_substr and connect by but it deals with only one column that has comma separated values. I have tried sub-query method also where I will be dealing with one column at a time in inner query and send the inner query output as input it outer query, this takes more time and the columns that hold comma separated values are more. So I cannot use the sub-query method.

Answer (score 0):

For one column you can `CROSS JOIN` a `TABLE()` collection expression containing a correlated sub-query that uses a hierarchical query to split the column value up into separate strings. For two columns, you just do the same thing for the second column and the `CROSS JOIN` takes care of ensuring that each delimited value in `column1` is paired with each delimited value in `column2`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f587c/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Id, Column1, Column2 ) AS
SELECT 1, 'A,B,C', 'H' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'D,E',   'J,K' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'F',     'L,M,N' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT t.id,
       c1.COLUMN_VALUE AS c1,
       c2.COLUMN_VALUE AS c2
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN
       TABLE(
         CAST(
           MULTISET(
             SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( t.Column1, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL )
             FROM   DUAL
             CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( t.Column1, '[^,]+' )
           ) AS SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST
         )
       ) c1
       CROSS JOIN
       TABLE(
         CAST(
           MULTISET(
             SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( t.Column2, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL )
             FROM   DUAL
             CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( t.Column2, '[^,]+' )
           ) AS SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST
         )
       ) c2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f587c/2/0)**:

```
| ID | C1 | C2 |
|----|----|----|
|  1 |  A |  H |
|  1 |  B |  H |
|  1 |  C |  H |
|  2 |  D |  J |
|  2 |  D |  K |
|  2 |  E |  J |
|  2 |  E |  K |
|  3 |  F |  L |
|  3 |  F |  M |
|  3 |  F |  N |
```

Comment: Thanks for immediate response but this works fine for 2 columns. I have many columns like this. Cross joining many times will have performance issue. Can you please suggest any other approach. :)

Comment: @Bhavani If you want to do it without `CROSS JOIN` then you will need to specify a way that for each row a subset of the delimited values in `column1` pair with a subset of values for `column2` and pair with a subset of values for `column3` otherwise, if you want to pair each delimited value in a row for `column1` with each delimited value for `column2` in the same row and pair it with each delimited value for `column3` in that same row then what you want is a `CROSS JOIN`!

Comment: @Bhavani Note - the table collection expressions are correlated back to the parent row so for `ID=1` the cross join will be between 1 row for the parent and 3 rows for the sub-query for `column1` and 1 row for the sub-query for `column2`. The correlation ensures that it will only generate the minimum number of rows required to pair each combination of delimited values.

Answer (score -1):

Below will give you an idea about to how to convert the comma separated string into rows. You can use this logic to satisfy your need.

```
select regexp_substr('a,b,c,v,f', '[^,]+',1,level)
from dual 
connect by level <= regexp_count('a,b,c,v,f', ',') + 1;
```

Comment: Thank you. But this works only for one column that holds comma separated values.

Comment: can't you apply the same logic to the other column as well?